# Prove $\ker(\phi)\ne \{e\}$

Tags: group-theory, sylow-theory, abstract-algebra

$G_1$ and $G_2$ are finite groups such that $|G_1|>|G_2|$ and $|G_2|$ divides $|G_1|$.
Let $\phi : G_1\rightarrow G_2\space$ be a homomorphism such that $\ker(\phi)\ne G_1$.

Can I conclude that $\ker(\phi)\ne \{e\}$?
It makes sense but I can't prove it.

Comment: A homomorphism $\phi$ is injective $ \iff $ $ \ker(\phi) = \{ e \} $. But how can $\phi$ be injective if $|G_1| \gt |G_2|$? I think you're right.

Comment: Hint: One of the group isomorphism theorems says that $G_{1}/{\rm Ker}(\phi) \cong {\rm Im}(\phi)$, and you know that $|{\rm Im}(\phi)| < |G_{1}|$ in this situation

Comment: So $|G_1/Ker(\phi)|= \frac{|G_1|}{|Ker(\phi)|}=|Im(\phi)|$ And since $|G_1|>|Im(\phi)|$ then $|Ker(\phi)|>1$ necessarily

Comment: That's it exactly

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$\frac{G}{\ker\varphi}\cong \varphi(G)$. Notice $\varphi(G)$ is a subgroup of $H$ so $|\varphi(G)|\leq|H|<|G|$.

Since isomorphism are bijections $|G|=|\ker\varphi||\varphi(G)|$. Since $|\varphi(G)|<|G|$ conclude $|\ker\varphi|>1$.

Notice you don't need divisibility.

---

Here is a shorter wording, a homomorphism is injective if and only if it has a trivial kernel. However an injective function from $G$ to $H$ if $|G|>|H|$ is impossible by definition.

Comment: The hypothesis $\lvert H\rvert>\lvert G\rvert\,\,$ is not satisfied.

Comment: oops, give me a minute

Answer (score 0):

Since you know that a homomorphism $ \phi : G_1 \to G_2 $ is injective $\iff \ker(\phi) = \{e\} $ you can proof by contradiction.

If we assume $ \ker(\phi)  = \{e\} $, it follows that $\phi$ is injective. This is impossible because of $|G_1| \gt |G_2|$ and both groups are finite.

Comment: Note that $\phi$ is not an Isomorphism, It is only a homomorphism so it is not necessarily injective(one to one).

Comment: I don't see any problem with that. You have to map all elements out of $G_1$ to an element in $G_2$.

You don't need an isomorphism for that.

Answer (score 0):

If $\ker \phi=\{e\}$, $\phi$ is injective and $G_1$ is thus isomorphic to a subgroup of $G_2$, hence $\lvert G_1\rvert \le\lvert G_2\rvert $, which contradicts  $\lvert G_1\rvert >\lvert G_2\rvert $. The only required hypothesis is the latter.